# Instantiating a legacy COM object in C# dynamically (using its ID in a string)

Tags: c#

In Python, when I want to use this COM object, all I do is `win32com.client.Dispatch("Myapp.Thing.1")` and it gives me an object which I can call methods and such on.

I want to do this in C# and, shockingly, I can't seem to figure out how. I do *not* want to use one of those automatically generated COM wrappers, for reasons I can't get into. I need to do the late binding, dynamic COM of times past.

I've tried doing this, but I get a Null Ref Exception on the invoke call.

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Myapp.Thing.1")
o = Activator.CreateInstance(t) 
t.GetMethod("xyz").Invoke(o, args)
```

Any example code that is able to load up a COM object by its name and use it in some basic manner would be ideal.

Comment: Jason first of all can you add some checks in your code and identify if t or o as null? if so and if you tell us, then we can start looking at it.

Comment: I just reran with those checks in place, neither t nor o is coming back null. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: and are you sure that the method xyz exists on that object?

Comment: Very sure, it's the same object I'm using in Python. I'm just translating this bit of code from Python to C# and oddly it seems like it's easier to use these old COM objects from Pyland

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your type is retrieved via GetTypeFromProgID, You don't actually have the type - you have a __ComObject type which wraps the COM object created - so it doesn't have method "xyz" on it.  Hence your null reference exception - `GetMethod("xyx")` is returning null.

In order to invoke the method, use `t.InvokeMember("xyz", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, args)` instead:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Myapp.Thing.1")
o = Activator.CreateInstance(t) 
t.InvokeMember("xyz", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, args)
```

Comment: Looks like it's working! And how do I get/set properties?? Thanks so much!

Comment: You still use InvokeMember, the `BindingFlags` parameter controls what you do - use `BindingFlags.GetField` or `BindingFlags.GetProperty`, and so on.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx

Answer (score 10):

You should to use the dynamic type it's exactly what it's for. You wont be able to type the instance without the wrappers. Instead you can do this.

```
 dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(
                                       Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyApp.Thing.1"));
 app.XYZ():
```